# Put a box on top of an image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to replicate a register/login form and I have an issue when it comes to the form itself.

Image of the web I'm trying to replicate:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBXBH.jpg)

My problem comes when I'm trying to make that rectangle on top of the `background-image`. I tried doing in with `::after` but I couldn't make the rectangle appear at all. I appreciate the help or any tip to make this work!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>

        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/styles.css">
        <title>Login form project</title>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="nav-container">

            <div class="navbar">

                <div class="c-name">Company Name</div>

                <div class="nav-options">

                    <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
                    <a href="#">About Us</a>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <h1 class="title main">Registration form</h1>
        <p class="title">for travel agency</p>

        <div class="form-container">
            
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@200;600&display=swap');

* {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; 
    color: white;
}

body {
    background-color: #1a1d2e;
}

div, a {
    color: #676f9d;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
}

/* Navigation and Title */

.title {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 0.5;
}

.nav-container {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar { 
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 40px 110px;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav-options a {
    margin-left: 20px;
}

a:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    height: 1px;
    width: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -2px;
    transition: .5s;
}

a:hover {
    color: #949fdf;
}

a:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
}

.main {
    padding-top: 30px;
}
/*  */

/* Log in form */

.form-container {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 65vw;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 100px auto;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-image: url(/images/samuel-ferrara-1527pjeb6jg-unsplash.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

.form-container:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
}

/*  */
```

I tried changing the displays and the widhts to see if there was something preventing the rectangle from appearing but nothing. I tried commenting the `background-image` to see if the rectangle was appearing behind it but there's no rectangle, with the inspect tools the ::after says that it has a 0x20 dimentions.

Comment: Are you talking about `.form-container:after`? By default it is `display:inline` which height and width will be ignored.

Comment: Hi @SyndRain thank you very much that was it. I changed the display on the `form-container:after` and it worked. Another quick question, If I'm to put content inside that :after how do I do it. Because I gotta ned to put the buttons and everything but I think if I put them inside the `div.form-container` the box will move downwards, right?

Comment: I gotta wrap my head around this one, I think `position: absolute` on the `div.form-container` and then creating a new child div to that and style it like I did with the `:after`. But that is for another question If I'm having trouble with that. Thank you!!

Comment: Yeah just use child elements in it. Was glad to help!